# const char*& as a function parameter C++

Tags: c++, function, reference, constants

I'm having difficulty solving a runtime issue C++, using Visual Studio 2010, it compiles fine though.

I have a function in a class in an API (from another DLL) with this signature:

```
ReturnCode GetValue(const char* &value) const;
```

I call it using:

```
ReturnCode Test::getStuff(const char* &value)
{
    ValueGetter valueGetter = myClass.GetValueGetter();
    ReturnCode returnCode = valueGetter.GetValue(value);
    return returnCode;
}
```

And that called using

```
const char* tempStr;
getStuff(tempStr);
```

What I'm seeing, is that, value is set correctly on the line after it calls valueGetter.GetValue(value).  But as soon as I go out of scope of the function by stepping one more time, the value becomes gibberish.    What am I doing wrong, and how do I do this correctly?  Hoping to not have to allocate memory, copy value, that I'd delete later.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong here. How are you calling `getStuff`?

Comment: What do you assign to value inside valueGetter.GetValue ? This seems to be a case of local value going out of scope and being destroyed (the one you assign to value). Also, it may be effect of optimization if you run the program in Release mode.

Comment: `value becomes gibberish` Does the value itself changes, or the memory pointed by this value becomes gibberish?

Comment: I'm running in Debug, the value starts 0xcccccccccccccccc <Bad Ptr> in function. After call 0x0000000002123290 "Test". As soon as step to the } brace, the pointer is the same, but the value becomes weird symbols/spaces/random. I updated the example, I forgot I had a temporary assignment there too, not a member variable in class.  I wonder if because that is going out of scope, so is the const char* pointer's memory it referred to...but is there any way to do what I'm doing without copying/allocating memory.

Comment: Can you still show to which string you point `value` to? And can you verify in the project settings which kind of runtime you're using?

Comment: Did you try the following?
        ReturnCode* returnCode = new ReturnCode(valueGetter.GetValue(value));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it returns a pointer to a variable that goes out of scope.
Either a variable local to `ValueGetter::GetValue` or a data member of `ValueGetter` (note that `valueGetter` goes out of scope when `getStuff` returns).

In the latter case, this should work:

```
ReturnCode Test::getStuff(std::string &value)
{
    ValueGetter valueGetter = myClass.GetValueGetter();
    const char* tempStr;
    ReturnCode returnCode = valueGetter.GetValue(tempStr);
    value = tempStr;
    return returnCode;
}


std::string tempStr;
getStuff(tempStr);
```

Comment: I guess that would work, although it forces me into std libraries.